# No matter what I do, no matter what I edit, every time I restart my computer my ELAN Smart Pad drivers reinstall

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I'm looking for a way to completely disable this.

As a bit of background: I'm using a Lenovo Z50-75 that is running the x64 version of Windows 10 Home. My problem is that no matter what I do, I cannot use my touchpad whilst using my keyboard, which is particularly annoying while gaming. I have edited the registry, uninstalled the driver, and tried to update it.

So, basically: I either need a way to completely remove the SmartPad driver and prevent it from reinstalling, or need to find a setting that'll make it possible for me to use both at the same time. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. This post also seems like a rant. This is a Q&A site, so you should ask a specific question. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Comment: @CharlieRB fixed!

Comment: Have you tried the manufacturer of the SmartPad direct, see if they have better drivers? Windows is not always the best judge in these matters.

Comment: Great! Take a minute to answer you own question with details of how you fixed it. That way if anyone else searches the site for the same issue, they will see how you resolved. it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially all I did was under device manager, I just uninstalled the drivers & driver software for the SmartPad. Still haven't restarted my computer, but once I uninstalled all of that, it's working like a charm!